# Using Angular Material 2 CSS without JS?

Tags: angular-material2

We're using the Angular flavor of Material 2 (https://material.angular.io/) for a main project, but would like to create a separate static (HTML/CSS) prototyping workspace that is able to access just the Material 2 CSS styles from that main project. The idea is that this separate directory will pull the compiled CSS from the Angular project, but allow for experimentation in HTML/CSS styling without configuring any JS.

Is it possible to compile the full CSS (components, typography, etc.) from the Angular Material 2 project, without needing AngularJS? It seems like there are styles being inserted by JS using the `<style>` tag.

Here's a basic demo of the SCSS file I've tried to build to load the Material styles:

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

@include mat-core();
```

This works for adding things like typography and the class names, but it doesn't add all of the possible styles for those classes. For example, the card component only gets very basic styles—it's missing the other styles such as padding that seem to be injected via JS.

---

I also tried the [material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/) project, which has compiled CSS [here](https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css). It comes very close to doing the job. But unfortunately just renaming `.mdc-` to `.mat-` is not enough. The component names and usage aren't quite the same.

For example, material-components-web uses BEM: `mdc-card__actions`.
Whereas the Angular versions calls it `.mat-card-actions`.

Comment: First - see this: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme. It isn't clear what you hope to achieve with the classes, but if you think you can reproduce a mat-card component for example (or any other) by adding classes to various DIV or other elements, you are mostly out of luck. The components don't work without the code - a lot of style is dynamic so the component code has to be executed for the style to work properly. This includes the dynamic 'style' tags that you've noticed as well as dynamic class assigments and JS animations - none of which exist in CSS.

Comment: @G.Tranter Argh, ok. Yep, you nailed exactly what I was hoping for: adding classes to divs to simulate how they'd look with the real dynamic stylings. Are these all defined the .ts files? I wasn't seeing any CSS in there for some reason. (Just curious, even if it's not possible to get the CSS styles out).

Comment: Very generally speaking (there will be exceptions) the style starts as 1-2 .scss SASS files per component (theming + style) and is then built along with global style into one big CSS for each of the prebuilt themes. But as I said, there are also dynamically applied classes, style attributes, and JS animations, so simply using the classes from the CSS only does part of the job. You would also have to get the structure/hierarchy of the classes correct as well (elements within elements), and handle interactivity. In short, you'd have to re-write most of not all of the component functionality.